# Rest API to return control then performing long running task

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a rest API that accepts a request and return just the acknowledgement to the caller, and then performing some long running task. Is it going to use "async Task"? I don't need the caller to get the result of the long running task. Is it possible?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't try to run long running processes in asp.net. Are you using .NET Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller function is unlikely to return async (unless there is some async/await calls being made during the long running task set up).

```
public IActionResult KickOffTask()
{
    Task.Run(()=>LongRunningTask());
    return Page();
}
```

Don't do this, by the way, Task.Run is not the best way to kick off such a task, it's just a quick example of how it /could/ be done.

Comment: Hi Neil, what is the recommended way then?

Comment: I would have a separate web service reading off a queue. The API would then post to the queue. It's very easy to set up queues or message buses on any cloud provider.

Comment: Understand. Why is Task.Run not recommended in a web service? Is it because it is not guarantee to release resources being used?

Comment: Web servers (especially IIS) are free to restart an instance at any time.  I seem to remember IIS restarts at least every 28 hours (by default).  Although there are mechanisms to inform the web application that the instance is restarting, they are really hacks because developers misused web servers.  If you want long running tasks, then you should be looking at WinServices (old tech), WebJobs (Azure), or some other kind of console app in a VM.